# If the pair of random variables X and Y have $f(x, y) = 180x^2y^2$ , for $0 < x, 0 < y$, and $x + y < 1$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise

Tags: probability, density-function

Find: $P(X + Y > 1/2)$

I know the answer is $63/64$. But how do you find that answer? I'm really struggling with what the bounds of integration would be for a question like this. Can someone show me?
I tried $\int_{1/2}^1\int_0^{1-x}180x^2y^2dydx$ but this gives me 11/32 which isn't the correct answer?

What do I need to do to derive $63/64$?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Could please send me questions like these ?. I want to practice as well.

Comment: These are all from the textbook I use to study, Introduction to Probability by Mark Ward Chapter 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch lectures on calculating area, volume using integrals there are tons of them on youtube.
Bounds are easy to figure out if you draw graphs. I will show you how it is so easy to solve these types of questions using graphs.

$P(X+Y\ge\frac{1}{2})=1-P(X+Y<\frac{1}{2})=\int\int f(x,y)dy dx$

The region inside the red outlined triangle is your required area where you have to figure out bounds.
[image]

Draw a vertical strip like shown below and go bottom to up(You can also start drawing a horizontal strip and go left to right).

[image]

From the bottom, we see $y$ touches the $x$-axis so $y=0$ and strip goes up and touches $y=\frac{1}{2}-x$ and drag thiis vertical strip left to right we see $x=0$ initially and goes till $x=\frac{1}{2}$

so we have just found our bounds.

$1-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}-x} f(x,y)dy dx$ is required probability.

Comment: Oh I didn't think about using the complement, that's genius! thank you!